# I am trying to use a stack to reverse the order of words in python

Tags: python, formatting, stack

At the moment my program will print each letter of the word on a new line rather then the words themselves will post full programs below.

```py
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)
```

Here's the script where I import my `Stack` class and use `reverseStr()`:

```py
import Stack

def reverseStr(mystring):
    s=Stack.Stack()
    for word in mystring:
        s.push(word)
    while not s.isEmpty():
        print(s.pop(),)
        
    
def main():
    mystring = "my name is jon doe"
    reverseStr(mystring)

main()
```

Comment: it seems the post messed up when putting in my second program this is my first post so sorry for that little inconvienence

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your string into words first, otherwise your string will be treated as a sequence of characters:

```py
>>> reverseStr(mystring.split())
doe
jon
is
name
my
```

If you want to print the reversed words on the same line, you can use `print(s.pop(), end=" ")`. Here's the result:

```py
>>> reverseStr(mystring.split())
doe jon is name my
```

If instead, you want to actually return a new string with the words reversed, you can use the accumulator pattern:

```py
def reverseStr(mystring):
    s = Stack.Stack()
    for word in mystring:
        s.push(word)
    reversed_words = []
    while not s.isEmpty():
        reversed_words.append(s.pop())
    return "".join(reversed_words)
```

Output:

```py
>>> reverseStr(mystring.split())
'doe jon is name my'
```

Notice the quotation marks, meaning that the string wasn't printed but actually returned from your `reverseStr` function.

PS - you can actually just return `self.items[-1]` in `peek()`, no need to recalculate the size of the stack.

Comment: I see what happened here I got the program to print on the line but how did you make the letters come out in the right order with the words still reversed?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I used the code you provided...

Comment: Sure thing @TheComedian , glad I could help. Can you go ahead and accept my answer? That way your question gets removed from the queue.